# Regex to split string on dots that are not inside brackets

Tags: java, regex

As the title says, I want to write a regex r such that
`Splitter.onPattern(r).splitToList("a.b.c.d[e.f.g]");` results in

```
[a, b, c, d[e.f.g]]
```

I have been playing around trying to get it right, but can't figure it out. I thought `"\\.((?!\\[)*)\\]*"` should have worked (to match any dot that is followed by a string not containing '[' that ends with ']'), but it still splits on all dots for some reason.

Comment: Your example is an edge case. How about changing your example to `"a.b[x.y].c.d[e.f.g]"` splitting to `[a, b[x.y], c, d[e.f.g]]` if that is correct, or is it is always the case that inner dots are always the last term?

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following, also assuming that `[` and `]` are balanced and not nested.

```
\.(?![^[]*])
```

Here is the [Online demo of regex](https://regex101.com/r/CtrCXL/2)

***Explanation:*** Match a dot not followed by 0 or more characters without a [ and followed by ].

Comment: This is finicky (and that is probably not solvable), for example, recursive [] won't work: `a.b.f[g.h[i.j]]` - this really doesn't feel like a task for a regex engine, but, credit where credit is due, for the base cases this does work.

Comment: Except it doesn't work in the general case. It only works for the edge case of the the last term to be split having the special case.

Answer (score 1):

Extract them with

```java
[^\[\].]+(?:\[[^\[\]]*])?
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/AStGH0/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\[\].]+                any character except: '\[', '\]', '.' (1
                           or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\[\]]*                 any character except: '\[', '\]' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]                        ']'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
```

**[Java example code](https://tio.run/##dVDdaoMwFL6uT3HoVdzYYdcT6RMUBr3UDFJNbWzUkBy7jdFnd2caOxgsBL7w/eUkrbqqp7a@TJPp3OAJWiZwJGPR60Z/4F5RddY@S/7RXxWR9n2WJG48WlNBZVUIsFemh69kE8lAihiug6mhY0kcyJu@KSQo34T0x7k5mV5ZWASYyyGHbfFWlkVZSpSPYvfC55WQDzLdbbO/wbAAJxUescK60HjCRs7OuzlODS5ivjJYDZ0zVot5gPS3Pv4DT79gvmYxMmK5mSOceT9zB4goIVfUIl2eCbwOn4F0h8NI6DhEtr9bGz@MTjyn89W3hPdtmr4B)**:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "[^\\[\\].]+(?:\\[[^\\[\\]]*])?";
        final String string = "a.b.c.d[e.f.g]";
        
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to assert that the next *bracket* char, if there is one, is not a closing bracket.

In regex speak, this is expressed as "is not followed by any number of non-brackets then a `]`":

```
"\\.(?![^\\[\\]]*])"
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/xbQoqPexzFXU2e).

---

Note: This does not work for *nested* dotted expressions like `a.b[c.d[e.f].g].h`.